# How to use tableValues in feComponentTransfer type "table"

Tags: svg

I am learning about SVG. So far it has been great but now I am stuck on the color transfer using table values. Here is an example:

```
<feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0 0 0"></feFuncR>
```

This function changed a solid bar of red color to black. I want to know how the `tableValues` attribute works so that I can figure out the color changes myself. I couldn't find any article that explained it in detail.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feComponentTransferElement

Comment: http://www.webplatform.org/docs/svg/elements/feComponentTransfer/

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#feComponentTransfer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How `feComponentTransfer` works is described in [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#filters-feComponentTransferElement).

How `type="table"` works is that you supply a list of N values describing N-1 interpolation regions.  These become the output values (V0 to V3) at various interpolation points.

Your table is "1 0 0 0". That's 4 values specifying the start and end interpolation values of 3 interpolation regions.

Input values 0    -> 0.33 are mapped to output values V0 -> V1 (1 -> 0).
Input values 0.33 -> 0.66 are mapped to output values V1 -> V2 (0 -> 0).
Input values 0.66 -> 1.00 are mapped to output values V2 -> V3 (0 -> 0).

So an input value of 1 for Red, which is what you said you were using, will be mapped to 0.  That's why your red element turned black.

An input value of 0 would be mapped to 1. An input value of 0.33 would be mapped to 0.  An input value of 0.2 would be mapped to:

```
Vk + (C - k/n)*n * (Vk+1 - Vk)
1  + (0.2 - (0/3)) * 3 * (0 - 1) = 0.4
```

Where Vk is the first table value (1), and Vk+1 is the second table value (0).  That's because 0.2 is in the first region (between 0 and 0.33).

Here's a graph to show how input maps to output.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300"
     font-family="sans-serif" font-size="16" text-anchor="middle">
  <g fill="none" stroke="lightgray" stroke-width="2">
    <line x1="100" y1="40" x2="100" y2="160"/>
    <line x1="90" y1="150" x2="410" y2="150"/>
    <line x1="90" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50"/>
    <line x1="200" y1="150" x2="200" y2="160"/>
    <line x1="300" y1="150" x2="300" y2="160"/>
    <line x1="400" y1="150" x2="400" y2="160"/>
  </g>
  <g fill="lightgray">
    <text x="50" y="100">Output</text>
    <text x="250" y="195">Input</text>
    <text x="80" y="55">1</text>
    <text x="80" y="155">0</text>
    <text x="100" y="175">0</text>
    <text x="200" y="175">0.33</text>
    <text x="300" y="175">0.66</text>
    <text x="400" y="175">1</text>
    <text x="50" y="245">Input</text>
    <text x="50" y="275">Output</text>
  </g>
  <g fill="black">
    <text x="100" y="30">1</text>
    <text x="200" y="30">0</text>
    <text x="300" y="30">0</text>
    <text x="400" y="30">0</text>
  </g>
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
            points="100,50, 200,150, 300,150, 400,150"/>

  <!-- filter a graduated rectangle to show ouput values -->
  <rect x="100" y="230" width="300" height="20" fill="url(#red-gradient"/>
  <rect x="100" y="260" width="300" height="20" fill="url(#red-gradient"
         filter="url(#example)"/>
  
  <linearGradient id="red-gradient">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(255,0,0)"/>
  </linearGradient>

  <filter id="example" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0 0 0"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer Paul. Just out of curiosity, where did you read about it? Did you figure it out yourself? I could not find anything written in such great detail about `tableValues` even after hours of Internet search.

Comment: The SVG specification (linked in the first line of my answer)

Comment: @NeenaVivek Strange, I spent seconds searching the internet to find the links I posted in comments, I suspect Michael did the same.

Comment: @RobertLongson I had trouble understanding "The table has n+1 values (i.e., v0 to vn) specifying the start and end values for n evenly sized interpolation regions." I thought this sentence meant a region of the image. That's why I found it very confusing. :D

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696831/d3-force-directed-graph-why-dont-the-flags-appear